# XLConnect: Where can I define a title for the exported table from R?

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am exporting multiple worksheets with the package ‘XLConnect’ to an .xlsx file.

I just went through the manual on http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf, but I miss a function to define a headline for the exported table. Can I define a headline/title for the exported table somewhere in the function below?

```
> library(XLConnect)
> wb <- loadWorkbook(paste0(date,"_analysis.xlsx"), create = TRUE)
> createSheet(wb, name = "sheetname")
> writeWorksheet(wb,dataframe,"sheetname",startRow = 2, startCol = 2, header = TRUE) 
> saveWorkbook(wb)
```

My desired solution would look like

```
> writeWorksheet(wb,dataframe,"sheetname",startRow = 2, 
+ startCol = 2, header = TRUE, title="Table 1")
```

I am aware that for the moment, I could write it in the xlsx file I am writing to, but this doesn't look like a proper solution for many reasons.

Comment: I think you are correct that there is no `title` argument when writing to files with `XLConnect`.

Comment: a workaround would be `headline <- ("Table 1")

+ writeWorksheet(wb,headline,"sheetname",startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = TRUE)`